# Random hide animation on Jquery UI Dialog box

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

I have this debug tool that used Jquery UIs dialog to display some information. Just for fun, I want to have a different animation for each time box is hidden (closed with the button, etc).

```
$('.devTool .devToolContent').dialog({
    autoOpen: false,
    modal: true,
    hide: "explode",
    width:'auto',
    dialogClass: 'devToolDialog',
    resizable: true,
    open: function(event, ui) {
        // Make the area outside the box clickable. When cliked the dialog box closes.
        $('.ui-widget-overlay').bind('click', function () { $(this).siblings('.ui-dialog').find('.ui-dialog-content').dialog('close'); });
    }
});
```

As you can see, I have the **explode** animation right now. Some of the other animations are **fade** and **slide** (see list on [Jquery UI documentation - Hide effects](http://jqueryui.com/docs/hide/#option-effect)).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
var transitions = ["explode", "fade", "slide"]

$('.devTool .devToolContent').dialog({
    autoOpen: false,
    modal: true,
    hide: transitions[randomFromTo(0, transitions.length - 1)],
    width:'auto',
    dialogClass: 'devToolDialog',
    resizable: true,
    open: function(event, ui) {
        // Make the area outside the box clickable. When cliked the dialog box closes.
        $('.ui-widget-overlay').bind('click', function () { $(this).siblings('.ui-dialog').find('.ui-dialog-content').dialog('close'); });
    }
});

function randomFromTo(from, to) {
    return Math.floor(Math.random() * (to - from + 1) + from);
}
```

It defines an array at the beginning which contains all the possible jQuery UI effects you'd like to choose. Then it picks a random one and sets it as the `hide` parameter for the `dialog`.

Comment: Works. On each page load the boxes get a new animation. Would be even more fun to have a random animation on each "close".

Answer (score 2):

As requested by the askers comment, here is a solution that adds a **different transition to each element**. It includes pretty much every reasonable transition in a whitelisting-fashion.

**The important part is the call to [jQuery each()](http://api.jquery.com/each/).**

*(Thanks Rory for the randomFromTo function!)*

```
var transitions = [
    "blind", // http://api.jqueryui.com/blind-effect/
    "bounce", // http://api.jqueryui.com/bounce-effect/
    "clip", // http://api.jqueryui.com/clip-effect/
    "drop", // http://api.jqueryui.com/drop-effect/
    "explode", // http://api.jqueryui.com/explode-effect/
    "fade", // http://api.jqueryui.com/fade-effect/
    "fold", // http://api.jqueryui.com/fold-effect/
    "highlight", // http://api.jqueryui.com/highlight-effect/
    "puff", // http://api.jqueryui.com/puff-effect/
    "pulsate", // http://api.jqueryui.com/pulsate-effect/
    "scale", // http://api.jqueryui.com/scale-effect/
    "shake", // http://api.jqueryui.com/shake-effect/
    "size", // http://api.jqueryui.com/size-effect/
    "slide" // http://api.jqueryui.com/slide-effect/
]

function randomFromTo(from, to) {
    return Math.floor(Math.random() * (to - from + 1) + from);
}
function addRandomTransitionTo(element) {
    var effect = transitions[randomFromTo(0, transitions.length - 1)]
    $(element).click(function() {
        $(element).toggle(effect);
    });
}

$("ol li").each(function() {
    addRandomTransitionTo($(this));
});
```

Enjoy!